# How to make expandable list on arrow click just like Youtube in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm an Android developer, I just want to expand the list as show in this image and I indicate it by red arrow when I click it, the list should be expand just like Youtube.

Please suggest me what should I do. How can I expand this on arrow click. If there is any suggestion for it please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can either use expandable listview or expandable recyclerview
refer this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/expand-a-recyclerview-in-four-steps/

Answer (score 0):

1.Create an expandable list adapter class extending base expandable list adapter as shown here...

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<String> expandableListTitle;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail) {
    this.context = context;
    this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
    this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
            .get(expandedListPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return expandedListPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String expandedListText = (String) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    TextView expandedListTextView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
    expandedListTextView.setText(expandedListText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
    return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
    return this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.expandableListTitle.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
    return listPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }
    TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
    listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return true;
}
 }
```

2. Create your list view. Define a expandable list view in layout xml

   ```
   expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
   expandableListDetail = <ArrayList>; // Provide your array list here
   expandableListTitle = new ArrayList(<Title of your list goes here>);
   expandableListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this,     expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail);
   expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
   expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

       @Override
       public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                   expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Expanded.",
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   });
   expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

       @Override
       public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                   expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Collapsed.",
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }
   });
   expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                   int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
           Toast.makeText(
                   getApplicationContext(),
                   expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)
                           + " -> "
                           + expandableListDetail.get(
                           expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(
                           childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT

           )
                   .show();
   }
   });
   ```